# Does flatMap method only flattens the stream and not map it?

Tags: java, java-stream

I see it's written everywhere that flatMap flattens and map the stream but in practical for example in the below program using only flatMap we can't perform mapping operation(changing it to uppercase). We need to separately use map method here.

```
List<String> uppercase = Stream.of(asList("A", "B"), asList("C", "D"))
            .flatMap(List::stream)
            .map(String::toUpperCase)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    System.out.println(uppercase);
```

Is my understanding about flatMap wrong? Can anyone please help to understand this - whether flatMap only flattens the stream or it can flattens & map both? If so then how can we write code for that?

Comment: It *has* mapped and flattened the stream: all the elements in a stream of lists of strings are mapped using `List::stream`, yielding a stream of streams of strings; this is then flattened into a stream of strings.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's only those specific method references that limit you. Using a lambda expression, you can still do both:

```
.flatMap(list -> list.stream().map(String::toUpperCase))
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

I should mention that it's only that sequence of method references that limited you, not that it's impossible to do it with method references. The key is the mapper you pass to it. Take these as examples:

```
Stream<String> uppercaseArray(String[] a) {
    return Arrays.stream(a).map(String::toUpperCase);
}
Stream.of(new String[] {"ab"}, new String[] {"cd", "ef"})
    .flatMap(this::uppercaseArray); //map and transform

// Or a completely different perspective
Stream.of("abc", "def").flatMapToInt(String::chars);
```

Comment: But there’s no advantage in putting the `map` step into the function here (and I’d prefer variants with less nesting for readability). It would be a different case if you require values from the surrounding context, like in this contrived example: `.flatMap(list -> list.stream().map(s -> list.get(0) + "  " + s))`

Comment: @Holger That's right. There's absolutely no reason to follow the second approach. I wanted to make it clear for the OP so that my first sentences don't get interpreted as "you can't do it with method references"

Comment: Since you can encounter already existing stream returning method in real life, the second example has its place. I was considering the first example, I wouldn’t use `.flatMap(list -> list.stream().map(String::toUpperCase))` instead of `.flatMap(list -> list.stream()) .map(String::toUpperCase)` because I think a chain is easier to read than nested constructs. But, of course, it’s perfectly valid for answering the OP’s question.

Answer (score 1):

For better understanding, see the return type difference in both case.

```
Stream<Stream<String>> i = listOfList.stream().map(li->li.stream());
Stream<String> j = listOfList.stream().flatMap(li->li.stream());

Stream<String> stream1 = Stream.of("A", "B");
Stream<String> stream2 = Stream.of("C", "D");
    
Stream<Stream<String>> result1 = Stream.of(stream1,stream2).map(str->str.map(s->s.toUpperCase()));
Stream<String> result2 = Stream.of(stream1,stream2).flatMap(str->str.map(s->s.toUpperCase()));
```

Comment: This Answer could use some more explanation to make clear your point.